# updating a deeply nested object in a collection

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a structure like the below -

```
var a = {
  foo: {
    dates: {'2018-11-29': 2020.55},
    strategies: [
      {
        expiryDate: '2018-11-29',
        projects: [
          {
            expiryDate: '2018-11-29',
            name: 'foo',
            value: 500
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  bar: {
    dates: {'2018-11-29': 2020.55},
    strategies: [
      {
        expiryDate: '2018-11-29',
        projects: [
          {
            expiryDate: '2018-11-22',
            name: 'bar',
            value: 650
          },
          {
            expiryDate: '2018-11-22',
            name: 'mario',
            value: 700
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to figure out a way to be able to easily update the internal `projects` collection with lodash. But i'm getting an error

i'm trying to do something like this

```
const finalTransformedData = _.mapValues(
  a,
  (value, key) => {
    value.strategies.map(strats =>
      strats.projects.map(trade =>
        Object.assign(
          {},
          { trade: 1 },
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

but i'm getting the below output - where am i going wrong?

```
{ foo: undefined, bar: undefined }
```

The example code above is a bit oversimplified but what i'm looking for is to easily manipulate the objects in the projects array somehow - essentially get something like this - replace the object in the array by looping through it and assigning a new object (got from object.assign)

```
foo: {
    dates: {'2018-11-29': 2020.55},
    strategies: [
      {
        expiryDate: '2018-11-29',
        projects: [
          {
            trade: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  bar: {
    dates: {'2018-11-29': 2020.55},
    strategies: [
      {
        expiryDate: '2018-11-29',
        projects: [
          {
            trade: 1
          },
          {
            trade: 1
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: to clarify, you trying to put { trade: 1 } inside projects ?

Comment: need to be with lodash, can't be pure JS solution?

Comment: yes - essentially replace any object within the projects collection with another object

Comment: Please, to let it totally clear, post in your question an example of a desired output

Comment: @CalvinNunes - sorry , added the desired output. also i dont necessarily need lodash but would prefer if i used some form of `map` or anything which returns a new array/collection

Answer (score 2):

Without `lodash` you can try loops as well `for..of`

```js
var a = {  foo: {    dates: {'2018-11-29': 2020.55},    strategies: [      {        expiryDate: '2018-11-29',        projects: [          {            expiryDate: '2018-11-29',            name: 'foo',            value: 500          }        ]      }    ]  },  bar: {    dates: {'2018-11-29': 2020.55},    strategies: [      {        expiryDate: '2018-11-29',        projects: [          {            expiryDate: '2018-11-22',            name: 'bar',            value: 650          },          {            expiryDate: '2018-11-22',            name: 'mario',            value: 700          }        ]      }    ]  }}

for(let { strategies } of Object.values(a)) {
  for(let s of strategies) {
    s.projects = s.projects.map(d => ({ trade: 1 }))
  }
}

console.log(a)
```

Comment: It's not explicit in the question, but, by its code, it seems OP wants an immutable approach.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `lodash` for this. Instead use `immer` - https://github.com/mweststrate/immer

You would do it like this:

```
const finalTransformedData = produce(
  a,
  (draft) =>
    draft.strategies.forEach(strats =>
      strats.projects.forEach(project => {
        project.trade = 1
      })
    ),
);
```